# python find a string & everything before and after

Tags: python, find

I have a bunch of HTML that I am downloading from a site once a week and need to grap few bits of info from it and not sure where to start.

I have around 100 of these that repeat in a file and want to just grab 2 lines out of it.

> > number2 ‑‑ computer 
> >     3 days ago on Jun 22, 12
> > 11,589 files / 4,363 MB

```
<td width="242"><div align="left"><span class="style9">
<span class="style9"><img src="pic.pn" width="32" height="32" border="0" style="vertical-align:text-top;" />number2 &nbsp;&#8209;&#8209;computer</span><br />
.....
<div align="left">License:<br />Backup:<br />Files:</div></td><td width="186" valign="top" nowrap><div align="left" nowrap>
<span class="black" nowrap><span class="black">Paid&nbsp;Unlimited</span>
<br />3&nbsp;days&nbsp;ago&nbsp;on&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;22,&nbsp;12<br />11,589 files / 4,363&nbsp;MB</span></td>
<td width="92" valign="top">&nbsp;</td></tr>
.....
</div></td>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You want a HTML parser - for this case I'd suggest BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @millimoose  :obviously he hasn't tried anything so far, cf the "not sure where to start"

Comment: `xpath` may be suitable for you

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's an admittedly passive aggressive suggestion that the OP should actually try something, anything, before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

First, try removing all the HTML tags from the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> def remove_html_tags(data):
...     p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
...     return p.sub('', data)
...
>>> stripped = remove_html_tags(unescape(html_source))
>>> stripped
u'\nnumber2 \xa0\u2011\u2011computer\n.....\nLicense:Backup:Files:\nPaid\xa0Unlimited\n3\xa0days\xa0ago\xa0on\xa0Jun\xa022,\xa01211,589 files / 4,363\xa0MB\n\xa0\n.....\n'
```

Then its a matter of normal search/split/re match

[`unescape`](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html) thanks to Fredrik Lundh

This should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to put a '\n' behind each line in your text,(if you load the file as string, it will already be that way.) Than you need to search that part in text and save the text in shorter form. Script underneath schould work if search and text are replaced by the right strings

```
#insurt text to search and to be searched
search = '<td width="242"><div align="left"><span class="style9">\n<span class="style9"><img         src="pic.pn" width="32" height="32" border="0" style="vertical-align:text-top;" />number2 &nbsp;&#8209;&#8209;computer</span><br />\n.....\n<div align="left">License:<br />Backup:<br />Files:</div></td><td width="186" valign="top" nowrap><div align="left" nowrap>\n<span class="black" nowrap><span class="black">Paid&nbsp;Unlimited</span>\n<br />3&nbsp;days&nbsp;ago&nbsp;on&nbsp;Jun&nbsp;22,&nbsp;12<br />11,589 files / 4,363&nbsp;MB</span></td>\n<td width="92" valign="top">&nbsp;</td></tr>\n.....\n</div></td>\n'


text = 'a\n'+98*search+'\nb'


changed = 0
for x in range(len(text)):
  if text[x:x+len(search)] == search:
    if changed >= 2:
       text = text[0:x]+' '+text[x+len(search):] # to place a replacement text, switch ' ' for 'replacement text'
    changed += 1


print(text)
```